# updating meta_key from the frontend

Tags: front-end, post-meta

I am wanting to update the meta_key in the database to reorder postmeta from the frontend.
I'm using jQuery UI drag and drop to move items into an order, I can update the values but the meta_key is not so easy. My meta_key and values are like this:

- add_task_0_assigned => value
- add_task_0_complete => value
- add_task_1_assigned => value
- add_task_1_complete => value
- add_task_2_assigned => value
- add_task_2_complete => value
- add_task_3_assigned => value
- add_task_3_complete => value

the values I can update from the frontend easily using super globals $_POST or $_GET but, is there a way to modify the meta_key to save and reorder in the database?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time for a detailed reply but some ideas:

1) Use arrays in the front end.  Make your input ID's like `add_task_assigned[]` and `add_task_complete[]` - these appear as arrays in the back end. It's not great practice, but it works.

2) Use an array in the backend.  Store the meta as

`array(
  [0] => array( 'assigned' => true, 'completed' => true ),
  [1] => array( 'assigned' => true, 'completed' => false )
  )`

3) As we're not quite sure how you've structured the HTML, the serialize method of jQuery UI sortable may also be handy: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

Answer (score 0):

Why not trigger an ajax call after an item is dropped that updates the database?  That way you can do it in php.  I don't know of a way to interact with a database in javascript that doesn't involve executing another file.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, I could do with seeing an example.